# RNN's Output Layer: How does it learn from its prev iterations if each Activation Vector is processed in parallel?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

First of all, are the activation vectors processed in parallel? If so:

That doesnt make sense since each previous activation vector feeds into the RNN as input. So if you're processing all activation vectors in parallel, its not learning from the previous activation vector?

I'm thinking of a RNN similar to how boosting behaves, where the activation vector "is updated" after each iteration. Please help me understand how the RNN can process the activation vectors in parallel even though its learning from the previous vector (as input) after each iteration.

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Comment: Intro to statistical learning 2nd edition

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what the text is saying without a direct quotation. I don't own a copy of the book, so I can't read or add it myself. But the term of art you're looking for is "back-propagation through time" or BPTT. These searches give a good starting point: `https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=backprop*+through+time+answers%3A1+score%3A1` and `https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bptt+answers%3A1`

Comment: The book part isn't important - please help me understand how the RNN can process the activation vectors in parallel even though its learning from the previous vector (as input) after each iteration? I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Just read up on back-propagation through time - the key part is that recurrent networks are, well, *recurrent*, so updates **do** depend on the previous activations.